# Unknown files appearing in my website 404 error page list without a referring URL

Tags: web-hosting, apache, 404, referrer

I've been seeing lots of entries in my `404` error page lists in my shared hosting account, which are attempts to hit sub URLs on my 'static' website, such as (usually with no referring URL):

```
/\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd%20website.rar
/aspweb.rar
/520.rar
/install.tar.gz
/sql.bak
/a.rar
/web123.zip
/aspweb.zip
/wwwroot.tar
```

These are aside from the usual attempts on `/wp-login.php`, etc...

I'm wondering if anyone can explain the above, is it just hacking attempts, should I be worried or ignore them? The site is going through CloudFlare over HTTPS.

Comment: By `404 error page lists`, do you mean your sever's error log, Webmaster Tools/Search Console, or something else?

Comment: those are attackers checking if the file exists. it there are no such files, its not a big problem. though cloudflare should block those requests.

Comment: @dan error pages appearing in my CPanel stats as being accessed and not available

Comment: I did a quick search just in case. I found nothing unusual. These are landscaping attempts looking for backup and/or install files. Nothing to worry about but plenty to block. It is a hacker looking for vulnerabilities by fingerprinting your server installs.

Comment: @closetnoc there are also a number of executable's in my list with pretty strange prefixes such as '/\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd' are they a problem?

Comment: Not if they do not exist. The \xef\xbf\xbd is just encoding. Nothing to worry about. Make sure that the files they are looking for do not exist. And see if you can block the IP address or domain name from accessing your site. Not sure how to do anything in cPanel. But we can help with blocking code for .htaccess if that helps.

Comment: For the record, 404 errors are not a problem. As long as you do not mind seeing them, you really do not have to block anyone. I just sticking an appropriate number of fingers in the air. Which specific fingers? I leave that up to how my mood strikes me at the moment.

Comment: @closetnoc I know how to block IP addresses in .htaccess, I'll have a look at the logs, usually they are coming from shared IP's though

Comment: That's alright. People forget that there are basically two types of IP address blocks, subscriber blocks (users) and everything else such as hosting. Most all attacks come from non-subscriber blocks these days so you will likely not be effecting users at all. I automatically block IPs, however, when I blacklist IPs, they have been compromised servers for the past several years. It is likely that a web host got hacked and now these compromised systems are looking to attack other servers. It is all script-kiddie stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these files which are being checked for including the `/\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd` which you mention in your last comment are attempts by attackers to identify common files which can be vulnerable in your web root which on a mis-configured website can provide an attacker the information they need to penetrate your site.

As an example sql.bak is a standard SQL backup file which an attacker can use to access your entire database as of the last backup if they can get it. aspweb.zip and the other similar files are commonly used by webmasters to package the site and upload it in a compressed file and then uncompress on the server, often leaving behind the compressed file. If an attacker got their hands on this file they would have a complete copy of your site source code if you used this method.

All of these log entries indicate attack attempts on your site which is common and can occur on any site. Definately attempt to block these connections from connecting to your site at all to add an extra level of protection to your site but don't assume the block will be 100% as no block is 100% as the attackers can find their way around it. Do a security audit on your site and make sure that vulnerabilities have been patched and that files such as these can not be accessed and if they must be on the server are not located in the web root.